# Network Drop Not Causing session$onSessionEnded to Trigger

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shiny app that I have authentication for. To protect it from credential sharing, I have created a database. For each user it stores pertinent information when they sign up. It has a field called logged in. It is initially set to zero. When a user logins in, it changes to 1. I have set up  session$onSessionEnded to trigger a change in the value back to 0. The user can always login as long as it is set to 0. It works great if the user closes the browser or when it times out. I have found recently when a network drop happens, it doesn't trigger the change back to 0. I have tried onStop and on.exit to no avail. Is there something that I am missing? Thanks